# @WorkerThread annotation processor

Tags: java, android

I really like the @WorkerThread/@UIThread/@AnyThread annoatations available in android.support.annotations library. I would like to implement something similar in a java project. However, I'm unable to find the sources for annotation processors. Does anyone know where to look or have a suggestion on how it can be implemented?

Comment: Did you find any sample code or workaround?

Comment: Any update? I'm looking for the processor for `UiThread`, but found nothing so far.